# ReSharper is extremely slow with JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013, resharper

The original issue is that everything slows and freezes.currently i'm using resharper 9 with VS 2013. When I start typing in a mark up file that contains JavaScript/Jquery or a JavaScript file and before I can get the 3rd or 4th letter out it is processing it and reformatting file. At times the IDE isn't responsive at all. I limit the number of files open and turn off analysis at the page level in hopes that that will limit the resources being used.

Answer (score 1):

Go to ReSharper → Help → Profile Visual Studio, and take a profile snapshot of the slow behaviour. This will be reported to JetBrains and the dev team can investigate. More details are available at [this support post](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/24083148-Visual-Studio-with-ReSharper-is-slow).

Also, try disabling any other plugins (both Visual Studio and ReSharper) to see if it helps - perhaps something's conflicting?